# ¿Cómo eliminar la ventana DOS que se queda abierta cuando se ejecuta mi .exe creado con py2exe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Quisiera que me ayudaran en lo siguiente.

Desarrollé un programa con `GUI` en `Python 2.7` utilizando la librería `Tkinter` y lo convertí en un archivo `.exe` con `py2exe`.

Todo funciona bien, excepto que cuando se abre el archivo `.exe` se abre una ventana de `DOS` (consola) en el fondo. Esta se cierra cuando uno cierra el programa y aparentemente no influye en nada, pero me gustaría que no saliera... ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes indicar a py2exe que tu aplicación es una interfaz gráfica usando el argumento `windows` en `distutils.core.setup` en vez de `console` para indicar el script principal de tu aplicación:

```
import sys
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    windows = ["main.py"],
)
```

Comment: JFSevilla, muchísimas gracias! Me funcionó a la perfección... llevaba tiempo buscando una solución y no la encontraba... Gracias!